# Cant access data from API Response

Tags: javascript, api

I'm making a request to a weather API and getting this response back:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Old Toronto",
    "local_names": {
      "gr": "Τορόντον",
      "ug": "تورونتو",
      "he": "טורונטו הישנה",
      "fa": "تورنتو",
      "pl": "Toronto",
      "ku": "Toronto",
      "en": "Old Toronto",
      "el": "Παλαιό Τορόντο",
      "de": "Toronto",
      "ar": "تورونتو القديمة",
      "pa": "ਟੋਰਾਂਟੋ",
      "oc": "Toronto",
      "ur": "پرانا ٹورانٹو",
      "es": "Toronto",
      "ca": "Toronto",
      "ps": "ټورنټو",
      "fr": "Toronto",
      "pt": "Toronto",
      "hy": "Տորոնտո"
    },
    "lat": 43.6534817,
    "lon": -79.3839347,
    "country": "CA",
    "state": "Ontario"
  }
]
```

How do I access the "lat" and "lon" data via javascript/Jquery?

I though the correct way to access this would be "response. lat" and "response.lon" but these come up as undefined. I noticed that the response is wrapped in '[]' so I have also tried "reponse[0].lat" which had the same result

Edit: Added code snippet of request:

```
fetch(coordRequestPath)
.then(function(response){
    
    cityLat = response[0].lat;
    cityLon = response[0].lon;
    console.log("Latitude: " + cityLat + " Longitude: " + cityLon);
})
```

Comment: `response[0].lat` looks correct for the date you shared, so if that doesn't work share your code so it can actually be debugged.

Comment: Have you parsed the response object to JSON? There should be a `.then(response => response.json()).then(data => //do something with data);`, or is your code snippet incomplete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know which shape has your API response body, but could you try this :

```
fetch(coordRequestPath)
.then(function(response){
    
    cityLat = response?.data?.[0]?.lat;
    cityLon = response?.data?.[0]?.lon;
    console.log("Latitude: " + cityLat + " Longitude: " + cityLon);
})
```

Answer (score -2):

Assuming that you have a JS dictionary listed above and it is in variable `weather`. You could access it using JS code like this:

```js
let lat = weather[0]["lat"];
let lon = weather[0]["lon"];
```

The reason why you don't use

```js
let lat = weather[0].lat;
let lob = weather[0].lon;
```

is because it is actually a dictionary, not an JS object.

Comment: In Javascript there is no 'dictionary' and the two syntaxes have an identical result.